# try-catch encouraged instead of type checking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typechecking

In python, I've often heard that instead of checking the type of a variable to determine whether you want to do a certain operation on it, you should just wrap the operation in a Try statement and handle the Exception in case you have the wrong input type.

Is the same true of javascript? i.e. should one preferentially use a try / catch approach instead of typeof?

Comment: Most times javascript is just going to try to convert it to the right type as it's loosely typed, so most operations would succeed, just not in the way you think they would.

Comment: try/catch blocks have a huge performance impact, so you should avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 That's ridiculous, and completely terrible advice. You shouldn't avoid something unless it actually turns out to be a performance bottleneck. Use the right tool for the job, and find a more performant solution if it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: @meagar Yea, let me put it this way: When you consider abusing the try/catch construct for something that can be done in a cleaner way, you should keep in mind that try/catch performs poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However lightweight is exception handling in any language, a rule of thumb is to always use exceptions for checking things that are *exceptional*.

What I mean it's that if your algorithm needs type checking in normal operation, then it's better to check explicitly the typing using a condition, if the type checking is done to detect to detect abnormal operation, it's better to raise/handle an exception.

Though, as Javascript is loosely typed, most of the time typing problems won't raise an exception, but instead work in a way that you do not always expect...

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I've got some function calls (database queries, mostly) that sometimes return undefined in normal operation, so these are not exceptional conditions. I'm now getting used to using things like `myVar=myDbCall() || defaultValue` and `if(!!myVar){myFunction}` which seem to be the idomatic ways to do these things in js.

Comment: (!!myVar) is unnecessary because if statements do the !! operation automatically.

Comment: @Derek, interesting and I didn't know, could you give a source about that?

Comment: @zmo I can't give you a source.. The fundamental behavior of the if statement is to do something if it is true, so it will always take the boolean value of whatever is parsed in the if statement. What you are doing with the !! statement is returning the boolean value.